# Standard errors for smooth coefficient kernel regression with npscoef {np}

Tags: r, standard-error

While fitting a Smooth Coefficient Kernel Regression with help of `npscoef {np}` in R, I cannot output the standard errors for the regression estimates.

The Help states that if `errors = TRUE`, asymptotic standard errors should be computed and returned in the resulting smoothcoefficient object.

Based on the example provided by the authors of the package "NP":

```
library("np")
data(wage1)
NP.Ydata <- wage1$lwage 
NP.Xdata <- wage1[c("educ", "tenure", "exper", "expersq")] 
NP.Zdata <- wage1[c("female", "married")] 

NP.bw.scoef <- npscoefbw(xdat=NP.Xdata, ydat=NP.Ydata, zdat=NP.Zdata)
NP.scoef <- npscoef(NP.bw.scoef, 
                       betas = TRUE,  
                       residuals = TRUE,
                       errors = TRUE)
```

Coefficients are in the object `coef(NP.scoef)` saved under `betas = TRUE`

```
> str(coef(NP.scoef))
 num [1:526, 1:5] 0.146 0.504 0.196 0.415 0.415 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Intercept" "educ" "tenure" "exper" ...
```

But should not the standard errors for the estimates be saved under `errors = TRUE`?
I see only one column vector. Not 5 for intercept + 4 explanatory variables.

```
> str(se(NP.scoef))
 num [1:526] 0.015 0.0155 0.0155 0.0268 0.0128 ...
```

I am confused. Hope for a clarification.

Comment: It seems that the se is for predictions to each of the 526 observations, if you go `NP.scoef$eval`, it seems to be the values for predictions, and `NP.scoef$mean` is the mean prediction for each value

Comment: @Derek Corcoran. Oh, I see. I thought of the standard errors of the estimates as that of the coefficients, but SE shows the standard error of the estimate as of the predicted regression line. It seems I have to compute SE of the coefficients myself.

Comment: were you able to calculate the SE @VladaPleshceva?